# Why Route tag can't render the component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

App.js code-

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className='py-3'>
        <Container>
           <HomeScreen />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My app.js was like this and everything was working fine. But after that I added Route tag and the code become like this

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className='py-3'>
        <Container>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomeScreen} />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

But after adding Route, HomeScreen is not rendering?
Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Which version of React Router? Is it possible to create a conde sandbox?

Comment: It's react-router-dom 6.2.1 @TusharShahi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` component **must** be rendered into a `Routes` component, and the routed components are rendered on the `element` prop as a `ReactElement` (*a.k.a. JSX*) since the `component`, and `render` and `children` function props no longer exist.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className='py-3'>
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
};
```